# Why is pySerial socket protocol not supporting fileno()?

Tags: python, sockets, pyserial, uart, pexpect

My goal is to be able to use the python expect module on a uart serial interface.

I'm trying to hook-up the pySerial (`serial`) python module to the `pexpect` module. However, I'm accessing the serial port remotely via a socket with the `serial.serial_for_url()` function using the socket protocol.

When doing so, it fails because `select()` needs to have `fileno()` define in the Serial object. I get the following error:
`io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno`

Why can the socket protocol use the `socket.fileno()`?
I tried it and it seems to work properly under linux.

Is there any reason why this shouldn't be supported by default in `serial.urlhandlers.protocol_socket.py`?

***Edit***:

I ran the following:

```
>>> import serial
>>> import fdpexpect
>>> fd = serial.serial_for_url('socket://10.28.1.15:7002')
>>> px = fdpexpect.fdspawn(fd, logfile=open('test.log','w'))
```

Note that you need hardware that have a uart-to-network bridge. I use a Digi32CM in that particular test, but it's not really relevant.

When I run the `fdspawn()` function, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "python2.7/site-packages/pexpect/fdpexpect.py", line 45, in __init__
    fd = fd.fileno()
io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno
```

pySerial `Serial` object does not define the `fileno()` function even though it is based on a socket and could use the socket fileno. When I tried adding it, the operation seems to work fine:

```
def fileno(self):
    return self._socket.fileno()
```

I'm wondering if I'm missing something?

Comment: You should show some code, preferably a small standalone program that can be cut and pasted into a file, and demonstrates the problem when executed.

Comment: Also, `fileno()` on the serial object is only supported on UNIX platforms, per the documentation. What platform are you on?

Comment: What is your version of pySerial?

Comment: I use pySerial version 2.7 and pexpect version 3.3

Comment: It's just not implemented. You already figured out how to implement it yourself. [The source.](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/pyserial/code/trunk/pyserial/serial/urlhandler/protocol_socket.py)

Answer (score 0):

For info, fileno() has been added to pyserial years ago, it is now working fine.